# Making all plugin specific rules strict

Tags: javascript, jasmine, static-code-analysis, eslint, software-quality

In `eslint.json` configuration, `ESLint` [allows to configure](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) rule strictness using the following logic:

- 0 - "off"
- 1 - "warning"
- 2 - "error"

Example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jasmine/valid-expect": 2,
    "eqeqeq": [2, "smart"]
  }
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to make all *plugin-specific* rules strict (code 2)?

In this case, we want all rules coming from `jasmine` ([`eslint-plugin-jasmine` plugin](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine)) produce an error if there is a violation.

I've tried to specify `"jasmine/*": 2` and `"jasmine": 2`, but both failed with a "definition for rule ... not found" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESLint doesn't have support for wildcards in configuration. However, you can request that plugin creator adds a shareable config into their plugin (http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins#configs-in-plugins) after that you can just add `extends: plugin:jasmine/all` into your config file to use config `all` provided by plugin.